# What's with the "Welcome to PLDI" comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

Every time a new user posts someone comments "Welcome to PLDI". What is the purpose of this and should it continue?

Comment: Some reviewers of the "first answers" queue like doing that

Comment: But what is the point? @mousetail if there is no point (and just noise) then should tghey be removed

Comment: The purpose ought to be obvious ─ it's to welcome people.

Comment: They should be removed after a few days yes

Comment: @mousetail and are they being removed after a few days?

Comment: @mousetail Why?

Comment: They are no longer useful after a few days

Comment: @mousetail It takes extra work to remove them and they don't create much clutter. If someone _wants_ to remove them I have no objection, but wasting CMs'/mods' time with that would be silly. No need to enforce the removal of a comment that takes 31 pixels of vertical space.

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms How much vertical space has no real effect on the cognitive load such a comment adds

Comment: @mousetail _Does_ it add any cognitive load? Maybe 10ms to see it's a welcome comment and skip over it? I genuinely don't see the issue here.

Comment: It's useless noise, anything I have to read but isn't relevant should be removed

Comment: @mousetail It's not intended for _you_ to read. In fact, most comments aren't. Comments which ask for clarification from a question's author aren't relevant to or directed at you either. Should they be removed?

Comment: Yes of course, I flag those as "no longer needed" once OP has edited their post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how most CGCC users greet newcomers in [Code Golf Stack Exchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com), and I suppose the referenced people doing this are also CGCC users, considering most of the early users of this website (me included) are current code-golfers.

IMO as @kaya3 said in comments, this is to welcome new contributers to the website, and unless it is obtrusive or clearly spam, I think it should be allowed to stay on.

Comment: I find that much of the "culture" of PLDI is imported from Code Golf

Comment: Welcome comments are not exclusive to code golf

Comment: Much our other culture (many answers, titling, etc.) is from Code Golf @mousetail

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch Again false, it's more like worldbuilding or UX in that regard. Titling has a fundamentally different purpose here than it has on code golf

Answer (score 2):

I'm a reviewer who uses `Welcome to PLDI!` in FA reviews. Here's my justification:

- Being welcoming has very few downsides, yet could easily be the difference between someone posting once, and coming back again
- There's a queue specifically for first answers. If all I did was upvote and Looks OK it, I'd kind of be going against the point of the queue
- Usually I use "Welcome to [site]!" as a way to start a comment with additional information, but most of the time on this site so far, the posts I've reviewed have been perfectly fine in my opinion

Comment: “yet could easily be the difference between someone posting once, and coming back again” — so why do you do something that can scare off new participants?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' You know what I mean. We don't need to play word games here.

Comment: Is there any data to support this?

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch Not to my knowledge. I could compile some but the sample size is limited.

Comment: Maybe take some from CGCC as well @RydwolfPrograms

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch Yeah that's where I'd have to take it from. PLDI hasn't been around long enough to meaningfully tell whether someone has or hasn't come back.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take look at this from a principled standpoint. We *have principles on this already*. The purposes and non-purposes of comments are laid out in /help/privileges/comment:

> **When should I comment?**
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

There's also a section titled "When shouldn't I comment?" with a non-exhaustive list, which I also encourage you to read. It includes:

> **When shouldn't I comment?**
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> [...]
>
> - Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use chat instead;

I find that worth mentioning because a fair number of new users will have an association bonus. So if you *really* want to welcome them, just invite them to a chatroom, and do it there.

You don't have to *like* these principles, but as a citizen of the Stack Exchange network, you are generally expected to follow them. (Am I a shining and perfect example? No. But I try for the most part).

And look- it's no so hard to actually just sneak in a "Welcome!" at the beginning of a comment that gives *meaningful feedback* on how to improve a question's quality, which a lot of new users struggle with. Just do *that*.

Answer (score -2):

At best, it's noise. At worst, it's stalking. Telling a new user “hey, I spotted that you're new!” can be very disconcerting for people who don't like the attention. [I've complained about this before](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3503/welcome-page-needs-more-welcoming/3772#3772). It wasn't enough to put me off because I was already used to Stack Exchange from other sites, but getting a response whose only content is ”we're tracking you“ does make me want to run away.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146387/discussion-on-answer-by-gilles-so-stop-being-evil-whats-with-the-welcome-to); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score -2):

Expanding on Rydwolf's first point, users who are welcomed into a site are more likely to stick around than users who are not welcomed. This is because the user will feel like the site is kind and is therefore a good site.

Comment: Is there any data to support this?

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch There is now: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63652016#63652016 (well, the data shows minimal difference, but definitely no _harm_)

Answer (score -2):

Depends on the site, I think. CGCC is a competitive site, so a greeting would be hepful.

However, PLDI is already a welcoming site because it lets you freely express your opinions. In that case, a welcoming comment would do the opposite effect, making the new user feel separate from the rest of the community.

Answer (score -3):

Welcoming new users is standard on all SE sites.

But in this case, during the current phase, effectively all the "new users" on this site are already familiar with SE and likely have accounts on several other SE sites.

So, unless someone has less than 100 points, the "welcome" message is nothing but noise.